# Android make Linear Layout childs flip

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with a linear layout inside a scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:layout_height="420px">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <TextView
            android:text="1st"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="100px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px" />

        <TextView
            android:text="2nd"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="100px"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100px" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The Textview that has text of "1st" shows on the top of the textview that has text of "2nd", is there a way that the "1st" shows on the bottom without changing the textview? because I plan to add textviews programmatically.

Comment: Anytime your plan is to start adding text views programmatically you should be asking yourself if a ListView would be better approach.

Comment: @FoamyGuy true, but ListViews inside ScrollViews are usually a headache

Comment: @FoamyGuy Is there a way to make the list start at bottom in a listview?

Comment: @jlhonora I assume the ScrollView was only there to account for when there are enough text views that they go off of the screen. If that is the case then a ListView will solve the problem without needing a ScrollView, so it could be removed.

Comment: @PotatoTiger Yes you can create a custom Adapter and inside of its getView() method you can insert the logic to reverse the indexes. Before you create the view and return it.

Comment: @FoamyGuy Thank you so much, it worked how I wanted with listview.

Answer (score 0):

Adding views programmatically to a LinearLayout is fairly easy:

```
LinearLayout yourLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
TextView view = new TextView(/* Context and other params */);
yourLayout.addView(view);
```

Rather than invoking `new TextView` directly, it is recommended to specify an XML for your text view and use a layout inflater:

```
TextView view = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext())
                .inflate(R.id.your_textview_layout, yourLayout, false);
```